# Text mining in R without RWeka

Tags: r, text-mining

I am following [this tutorial](https://rpubs.com/brianzive/textmining) to get a list of most recurrent n-word phrases from a dataframe that has approximately 2m records (text in multiple languages).
Everything works fine till the last couple of steps

```
# tokenize into tri-grams
trigram.twitterTdm <- tm::TermDocumentMatrix(text.corpus["twitter"], control = list(tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))
```

where it ends up using TrigramTokenizer (from the RWeka package) to actually create the tokens. Issue is that RWeka has an rJava dependency which is not supported on our server.

**Are there any other packages in R which I can use to get most recurrent 2/3/4 word phrases from a dataset? Any tutorials would be extremely useful (novice in this area)**

Comment: You might take a look at the CRAN view for [NLP](https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=NaturalLanguageProcessing)

Comment: maybe check the quanteda package. The developer answers questions at SO.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the tm library NLP should be installed as well and the code below should work. Adjust the tokenizer to your needs.

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
crude <- tm_map(crude, stemDocument)



# change 3 into whatever you need for a differenct n-gram
NLPtrigramTokenizer <- function(x) {
      unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 3), paste, collapse = " "), use.names = FALSE)
}

tdm_NLP <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control=list(tokenize = NLPtrigramTokenizer))

inspect(tdm_NLP)
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 2252, documents: 20)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2485/42555
Sparsity           : 94%
Maximal term length: 32
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
Sample             :
                       Docs
Terms                   144 236 237 242 246 248 273 489 502 704
  158 mln bpd             3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  ali alkhalifa alsabah   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
  arabian oil minist      0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
  barrel per day          0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
  decemb opec accord      0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
  emerg opec meet         0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
  hold futur posit        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
  industri sourc said     1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
  sheikh abdulaziz said   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0
  world oil price         0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
```

Also you might be interested in reading [Tidy text mining with R](http://tidytextmining.com/index.html)